# Custom UiTabBar height showing different on iPhone X

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar, iphone-x

I wanted to have my tab bar be a little taller then it is by default so I used this:

```
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
    // - 40 is editable , I think the default value is around 50 px, below lowers the tabbar and above increases the tab bar size
    tabFrame.size.height = 64
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 64
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
```

This has worked in the past and still works for iPhone 5-8,

[image]

but iPhone X seems to display a gap between the UiTabBar and the content view.

[image]

If I remove that code this is what it looks like

[image]

So my question would be if it's possible to use my custom height for the iPhone X and if so what do I need to do differently to make it display correctly? Visually the I think the default size is too small, and the labels are too close to the icons.

Comment: Try increasing TabBar Height by 5-10.

Comment: kinda silly that is the solution, but yeah that's what ended up working for me...